# How to read a file and enter data info 2D array with skipping certain parts

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to stream a file and input its contents into a 2D array. I have this code which successfully reads all the contents of the file. I want to adjust my code in such a way that it skips the first line of the file (#  R1  R2  R3  R4  R5) and the number starting on each line of the file. In a way, I would like to remove all elements which have X = 0 and Y = 0 in arr[X][Y]. I would like to do this while reading the file with the scanner, rather than crating a new array and going through the first one and storing the needed data in the new one.

This is the streamed file:

```
#   R1  R2  R3  R4  R5
1   J   S2  Q   S2  J
2   J   S2  Q   S2  J
3   J   S2  Q   S2  J
4   J   S2  Q   S2  J
5   J   Q   S5  Q   J
6   S3  Q   S5  Q   S3
7   S3  Q   S5  Q   S3
8   S3  Q   S5  Q   S3
9   S3  S1  S5  S1  S3
10  A   S1  S5  S1  A
11  A   S1  K   S1  A
12  A   S1  K   S1  A
13  A   S1  K   S1  A
14  A   S1  K   S1  A
15  S2  A   K   A   S2
16  S2  A   S3  A   S2
17  S2  A   S3  A   S2
18  S2  A   S3  A   S2
19  S2  A   S3  A   S2
20  Q   S5  S3  S5  Q
21  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
22  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
23  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
24  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
25  S4  K   S2  K   S4
26  S4  K   S2  K   S4
27  S4  K   S2  K   S4
28  S4  K   S2  K   S4
29  S4  K   S2  K   S4
30  K   S4  S2  S4  K
31  K   S4  A   S4  K
32  K   S4  A   S4  K
33  K   S4  A   S4  K
34  K   S4  A   S4  K
35  S1  S4  A   S4  S1
36  S1  A   S1  A   S1
37  S1  A   S1  A   S1
38  S1  A   S1  A   S1
39  S1  A   S1  A   S1
40  Q   S3  S1  S3  Q
41  Q   S3  Q   S3  Q
42  Q   S3  Q   S3  Q
43  Q   S3  Q   S3  Q
44  Q   J   Q   J   Q
45  S2  J   S4  J   S2
46  S2  J   S4  J   S2
47  S2  J   S4  J   S2
48  S2  S2  S4  S2  S2
49  S2  S2  A   S2  S2
50  J   S2  A   S2  J
51  J   S2  A   S2  J
52  J   Q   A   Q   J
53  J   Q   A   Q   J
54  J   Q   J   Q   J
55  S5  Q   J   Q   S5
56  S5  J   J   J   S5
57  S5  J   J   J   S5
58  S5  J   S1  J   S5
59  S5  J   S1  J   S5
60  A   S3  S1  S3  A
61  A   S3  S1  S3  A
62  A   S3  Q   S3  A
63  A   S3  Q   S3  A
64  A   K   Q   K   A
65  S1  K   Q   K   S1
66  S1  K   S4  K   S1
67  S1  K   S4  K   S1
68  S1  Q   S4  Q   S1
69  S1  Q   S4  Q   S1
70  K   Q   K   Q   K
71  K   Q   K   Q   K
72  K   J   K   J   K
73  K   J   K   J   K
74  K   J   K   J   K
75  S3  J   J   J   S3
76  S3  NA  J   NA  S3
77  S3  NA  J   NA  S3
78  S3  NA  J   NA  S3
```

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reels_template.txt")));

   int arrX = 78;
   int arrY = 6;
   String [][] arr = new String[arrX][arrY];
   String[] line = {};



     for (int i=0; i<arrX; i++) {
         if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         line = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
         }
        for (int j=0; j<arrY; j++) {        
            arr[i][j] = line[j] + " ";                             
        }
     }


   for (int i = 0; i < arrX; i++) {
       for ( int j = 0; j < arrY; j++) {
           System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

}
```

This is the output of the above code:

```
 # R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 
 1 J S2 Q S2 J 
 2 J S2 Q S2 J 
 3 J S2 Q S2 J 
 4 J S2 Q S2 J 
 5 J Q S5 Q J 
 6 S3 Q S5 Q S3 
 7 S3 Q S5 Q S3 
 8 S3 Q S5 Q S3
```

This is the desired output:

```
 J S2 Q S2 J 
 J S2 Q S2 J 
 J S2 Q S2 J 
 J S2 Q S2 J 
 J Q S5 Q J 
 S3 Q S5 Q S3 
 S3 Q S5 Q S3 
 S3 Q S5 Q S3
```

EDIT: Problem has been solved by using the scanner to read the first line before the loop removing the unwanted row and readjusting the second for loop. Code sample:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reels_template.txt")));

   final int arrX = 78;
   final int arrY = 5;
   String[][] arr = new String[arrX][arrY];
   String[] line = {};


     line = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
     for (int i=0; i<arrX; i++) {
         if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         line = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
         }
        for (int j=0; j<=arrY; j++) {  
            if (j!=0) {
            arr[i][j-1] = line[j] + " "; 
           }
        }
     }


   for (int i = 0; i < arrX; i++) {
       for ( int j = 0; j < arrY; j++) {
           System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this (even though rather obvious), would be to simply not read the elements that you don't want to read. Your code would be modified like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reels_template.txt")));

   int arrX = 77;
   int arrY = 4;
   String [][] arr = new String[arrX][arrY];
   String[] line = {};

   sc.nextLine();  // remove the first line from the scanner

   for (int i=0; i<arrX; i++) {
     if (sc.hasNextLine())
       line = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");

       for (int j=0; j<arrY; j++) {        
         arr[i][j] = line[j+1] + " "; //always skips first element of 'line'                           
       }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < arrX; i++) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < arrY; j++) 
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]);

      System.out.println();
    }

}
```

But, this piece of code will only work with a file with a specific number of "lines" and a specific number of elements in each line. How about making it more 'dynamic' ?

The following method, will add every line of the file as a **`String`**, into an **`ArrayList<String>`**. It will then remove the first unwanted line and after that, the first number in front of each line.

```
public ArrayList<String> readFileText (String filename){
    //ArrayList to hold all the lines
    ArrayList<String> lines = null;

    //Get lines of text (Strings) as a stream
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))){
        // convert stream to a List-type object
        lines = (ArrayList<String>)stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("\nCould not read lines of text from the file.\n" +
                "Reason: parameter \"" + ioe.getMessage() + "\"");
    }
    catch (SecurityException se){
        System.out.println("Could not read the file provided." + 
          "Please check if you have permission to access it.");
    }

    lines.remove(0);  //Remove the first line of the file. Line at index 0.

    for(String line : lines)
        //Fine the first occurrence of white-space in each line,
        //and use that substring, to remove the number of the line.
        line = line.substring(line.indexOf(" "));

    return lines;
}
```

To use this method in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> allFileLines = readFileText("reels_template.txt");

    for(String line : allFileLines)
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

See how more elegant the main method looks now? This is how methods are used. Always aim to make them have a more *dynamic* nature, rather than a hardcoded style.

Comment: I believe I solved the second part in a similar way just now. As for the first part I think using continue is a better option so I will update my code accordingly. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You might want to think about some edge cases. For example, what happens when you read an empty file? Or, what happens when `int arrX` is larger than the lines you are going to have ? (Try setting arrX to 120 and see what happens, or try parsing an empty file)

Comment: Update: Using continue does not fill the first row of the array with any values leaving it with nulls. I did not bother to copy your whole code so this might occur because of the way I have coded my function.

Comment: @VaskoVasilev Have a look at the updated answer. See the alternative method I posted.